# Programming with MicroStation SDK in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microstation

I have a customer who wants me to rewrite some VBA code used with MicroStation into C# and using Windows Forms. My customer has a copy of MicroStation installed but I don't so I understand that they will be responsible for testing the code that I develop.

I have downloaded and installed the MicroStation SDK from Bentley but I can't find the relevant references to add to Visual Studio that will allow me to develop against this SDK using C# and .NET.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking.  What's broken and what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I have tried to find an interop assembly (along the lines of Bentley.Interop.MicroStationDGN.dll) somewhere in the SDK but to no avail.

Tutorials such as this one; http://communities.bentley.com/other/old_site_member_blogs/bentley_employees/b/bills_blog/archive/2007/10/22/using-c-in-microstation-v8-edition, refer to adding those references from MicroStation as the first step. I don't have MicroStation itself, but I do have the SDK and expected there to be something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assemblies are only installed when you install MicroStation. Try installing the 30-day trial, then go look in the Extensions or .Net tabs in Add Extension.

ftp://ftp.bentley.com/pub/help/microstationsdk/08090451en/readme_mdlsdk.htm

MicroStation SDK QuickInstall Guide

Before you start

•The MicroStation SDK requires software libraries (DLLs) that are delivered with MicroStation V8 XM Edition. As such, make sure MicroStation V8 XM Edition is installed on your computer before you install the MicroStation SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You must have MicroStation installed to use the SDK.
There are many DLLs and assemblies that you won't have if you installed only the SDK.
There is a *MicroStation Programming Forum* where you will get focussed answers:
http://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/f/343173